# How to make controlled exchanges in an online-game?

Tags: c#, java, mathematics, javascript, python

There is an online game in which you can collect things of different values: ordinary, epic, legendary. The cheapest things are ordinary, the more expensive are epic, and the most expensive are legendary.

If you have collected 10 things of the same value, then you can exchange them for one thing with a value higher. For example, if you collected 10 things of epic value, then you can exchange them for one legendary thing.

After such an exchange, the user can go into minus or plus, because 10 things with a value lower can total be worth more than one thing with a value higher or vice versa. The user can drop a thing worth 25% to 400% of the exchange value.

How can I make such exchanges controlled so that someone can get a good profit from these exchanges, someone stay at zero, and someone go minus? But the most important condition is that, as a result, the online game is in plus with exchanges.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a job for [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value)!

- Take all the epic items in your game.
- For each one, compute its value, and its probability of dropping / being acquired by the player.

  This second one can be a bit tricky to calculate, depending on your game systems.

  - If you all items are equally likely, or you have one master drop table with probabilities for each item, it's easy.
  - If there are lots of different ways of getting an item, and they depend on what actions the player is choosing to pursue, then you may need to estimate it using a "typical" or "optimizing" model player, or a Monte Carlo simulation.

    If this is a game that's already live or in playtesting, you can use telemetry data from real players to see how often an item is appearing, as-played, which can often differ in subtle or dramatic ways from what we predicted on paper.

  As long as you get a decent approximation of relative frequency though, this technique will still lead you to useful results, even if they're not exact to the last decimal point. ;)
- For each item, **multiply its value by its probability**, and sum up the total across all epic items.
- Divide by the probabilty of getting an epic at all.

What you've just calculated is the **expected value of one epic item**. That is, if you played for a long time and got 1000 epic items, we'd expect the total value to be about 1000 times this representative average value.

Now do the same for the legendary items that you award from the trade-in.

Subtract ten times the expected value of an epic from the expected value of a legendary. The number you have left is your **expected profit on the trade**.

- If it's positive, then even if some individual trades might lead to a loss, when iterated across many trades players would still expect to make about this much profit per trade on average.
- If it's negative, then a rational player will expect to lose on the trade, and will probably avoid using this system.

Now you can tune your values and probabilities until the expected profit is in a range that looks right for your target experience. Just keep in mind loss aversion: players feel the sting of a bad trade more intensely than the elation of a good one, so you often need to tip the scale a little extra in the player's favour for it to "feel" fair or profitable.

One other wrinkle to watch for here: if the value of the legendary you award has no connection to the value of the epics that were sacrificed, then players will notice, and they'll save up only the low-value epics to use for this trade, and spend their high-value epics elsewhere (assuming some alternative use exists, like selling it to an NPC/shop or another player). This will shift the expected value of an epic-that-gets-traded, so it will be lower than the expected value for an epic overall, increasing the expected profit for players who go this route.

You can either factor that into your calculations, and balance for both a player who trades everything and a player who picks only the duds to trade, or you can bias your legendary selection so that you preferentially choose low-value legendaries for low-value sacrifices, and vice versa, so players perceive trading high-value epics as worthwhile for the better shot at high-value legendaries.

Comment: It still turns out to be some kind of randomness. We need precise control. Nevertheless, many thanks to you for prompting this idea and explaining it.

Comment: Then can you please edit your question to explain what kind of precise control you're looking for, in detail?